# How to expose service in AKS NginX Ingress

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

I have a service which exposes a "hello world" web deployment in "develop" namespace.

Service YAML

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hello-v1-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-v1
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

To test if the page is working properly, I run "kubectl port-forward" and the page is displayed successfully using the public IP.

Edit:
Then the Ingress is deployed but the page only displays within vnet address space

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app
    version:  1.0.0
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace:  develop
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: hello-v1-svc
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
```

Ingress Rules

```
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /   hello-v1-svc:80 (10.1.1.13:8080,10.1.1.21:8080,10.1.1.49:8080)
```

What step am I skipping for the page to display?

Comment: can you provide any logs you have?

Comment: I am not sure where to get those Logs, but I think this issue it is related to the load balancer since it handles the public ip. The ingress controller only have 2 IPs, one for the kubernetes internal network and other for the vNet.

Comment: Which ingress controller have you deployed?

Comment: NginX Ingress Controller, In my last tests, the application is accessible only from the Vnet IP. But I don't know how to do it through the public ip

Comment: By VnetIP do you mean pod IP or node IP? can you get list of services with kubectl get svc -A command?

Comment: 1. for NginX Ingress Controller i believe you should use `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` annotation. 2. what IP are you using trying to connect? I mean is tthat EXTERNAL_IP from nginx LoadBalancer?

Comment: Maybe it is related to this annotation: "service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal". Controller is set to "True".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to answer your comment:

> Maybe it is related to this annotation:
> "service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal". Controller
> is set to "True"

`service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"` annotation is typicaly used when you create an ingress controller to an internal virtual network. In case of this annotation , the ingress controller is configured on an internal, private virtual network and IP address. No external access is allowed.
You can find more info in [Create an ingress controller to an internal virtual network in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-internal-ip) article.

Reproduced your case, created AKS cluster and applied below yamls. It works as expected so please use

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: develop
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world-deployment
  namespace: develop
  labels:
    app: hello-v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-v1
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-v1
        image: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hello-v1-svc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: hello-v1
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: develop
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: hello-v1-svc
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
```

List of my services

```
vitalii@Azure:~$ kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE       NAME                             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
default         hello-v1-svc                     ClusterIP      10.0.20.206    <none>         80/TCP                       19m
default         kubernetes                       ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>         443/TCP                      83m
ingress-basic   nginx-ingress-controller         LoadBalancer   10.0.222.156   *.*.*.*   80:32068/TCP,443:30907/TCP   53m
ingress-basic   nginx-ingress-default-backend    ClusterIP      10.0.193.198   <none>         80/TCP                       53m
kube-system     dashboard-metrics-scraper        ClusterIP      10.0.178.224   <none>         8000/TCP                     83m
kube-system     healthmodel-replicaset-service   ClusterIP      10.0.199.235   <none>         25227/TCP                    83m
kube-system     kube-dns                         ClusterIP      10.0.0.10      <none>         53/UDP,53/TCP                83m
kube-system     kubernetes-dashboard             ClusterIP      10.0.115.184   <none>         443/TCP                      83m
kube-system     metrics-server                   ClusterIP      10.0.199.200   <none>         443/TCP                      83m
```

Sure for security reasons I hide EXTERNAL-IP of nginx-ingress-controller. Thats the IP you should use to access page.

MOre information and exampke you can find in [Create an ingress controller in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic) article